# Magento 2: How to add cart summary after Update shopping cart button?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shopping-cart

how can i get cart summary button after "update shopping cart" button ??

[image]

This is mobile view, don't worry about desktop view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i get the solution.
Override checkout_cart_index.xml in your current theme and find below container and add code after this container.

```
<container name="checkout.cart.items" as="with-items">

----------
---------- 

<container name="checkout.cart.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">

 ------------

 </container>

  <!-- Add custom Checkout button after cart container for only mobile view-->
 <container name="custom.checkout.button" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mobile-checkout-button">
     <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.custom.bottom" template="cart/methods.phtml">
        <container name="checkout.cart.methods.custom" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
             <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.custom.bottom" template="onepage/link.phtml" />
             <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.custom.buttons" />
       </container>
     </block>    
 </container>
 <!--End-->
```

Hope so it helps you.